# Copy a paragraph into the same document(python 3.x, docx)

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

Let's say I have a certain paragraph in my docx document with certain text formatting, for example: 
"Foo **bar**" 
I want to make something like a template of this paragraph to copy it into the same document multiple times.
Copying text like in the example means loosing text formatting.

```
from docx import Document

document = Document('input.docx')
template = document.paragraphs[0]
for x in range(100):
    document.add_paragraph(template.text)
document.save('output.docx')
```

Is there any generic way to do it with python-docx library? 
Other solutions for python and django in particulary are appreciated as well!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is a bit too abstract to allow a useful answer. In general you would need to go down to the next level (runs inside paragraphs) because that's where the character formatting is. If you can make your particular objective a bit more concrete, a better answer might be possible. I'll take a crack below with these provisos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your simple example, you could do something like this:

```
def clone_run_props(tmpl_run, this_run):
    this_run.bold = tmpl_run.bold
    ... maybe other possible run properties ...

template_paragraph = ... however you get this ...
new_paragraph = document.add_paragraph()
for run in template_paragraph:
    cloned_run = new_paragraph.add_run()
    clone_run_props(run, cloned_run)
    cloned_run.text = ... however you get this ...
```

This approach will work when the character formatting is *directly applied*, but not when it's indirectly applied, such as via a character style.

Comment: I'm looking for a more generic solution, smth like  when a user uploads a docx template(I don't even have to know what template is it) and as a result recieves a document with certain amounts of those templates filled with different information from database(such as names, surnames etc.). Filling in for a single document works great and fast, but I'm looking for a solution for queryset :) Thanks for your response!

Comment: I would need to see an example. There are a lot of particulars you haven't mentioned, like how you know where to put what and what restrictions the "template" document needs to comply with. If you're looking for general document templating, like putting substitution strings like `{{name}}` in the text and then doing replacement, you're talking about a different (and quite challenging) problem. You can find more on that by searching on 'python-docx template substitution'.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm talking about, thanks for your advice - I'll try to look for it. But so far the problem is not with replacing, regular expressions are doing great for simple replacements, I'm just failing to multiply content for multiple objects in query-set.